# Post to Twitter from MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter, restsharp

I saw couple of libraries which we can use to post to twitter. But I want to create my own as later we need to extend this for other social networks also .

I am using the RESTSharp to make things little easy for me.

In my controller, I wrote 2 methods..

```
public ActionResult TwitterLogin()
        {
            var authorizeUrl = TwitterService.Authorize();
            if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(authorizeUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(authorizeUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

public ActionResult AuthorizeCallback()
        {
            TwitterService.AuthorizeCallback();
            return View();
        }
```

In Twitter Service

```
public string Authorize()
    {
        client = new RestClient(BaseUrl) {Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForRequestToken(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, CallbackUrl)};
        var request = new RestRequest("oauth/request_token", Method.POST);
        var response = client.Execute(request);
        if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(response.Content);
            oauth_token = qs["oauth_token"];
            oauth_token_secret = qs["oauth_token_secret"];

            request = new RestRequest("oauth/authorize");
            request.AddParameter("oauth_token", oauth_token);
            return  client.BuildUri(request).ToString();
        }
        
        return String.Empty;
    }

public void AuthorizeCallback()
    {
        var verifier = "123456"; // <-- Breakpoint here (set verifier in debugger)
        var request = new RestRequest("oauth/access_token", Method.POST);
        client.Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForAccessToken(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, verifier);
        var response = client.Execute(request);

        var qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(response.Content);
        oauth_token = qs["oauth_token"];
        oauth_token_secret = qs["oauth_token_secret"];
    }
```

Now my concern is
Whether i am doing it right ?

Regarding Oauth, from what I understood , we create a request token from the twitter, ask the user to authorize it and use it to get an accesss Token and use it for signing other requests. I wrote this code primarly looking this link
https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp.IntegrationTests/oAuth1Tests.cs

Whether we can write this any better ?
Also somebody could guide me on this , how to use the RestSharp to create OAuth requests to use the API's like twitter. Most of the internet references are based on the custom libs